# Errors from BrowserRouter when using Routes and links in React with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, typeerror, create-react-app

I have been learning and practicing with react-router-dom and I have gotten these errors every time. I tried researching why this was happening before but simply cutting and pasting the code seemed to fix it (no idea why). However, it is now not working despite my best attempts. The only difference is that I am trying to use TypeScript for the first time and so used `create-react-app --template typescript`.

The errors:
[8 warnings/errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2u11.png)

Here is my code:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import SearchPage from './pages/Search.page';
import HomePage from './pages/Home.page';
import ProfilePage from './pages/Profile.page';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    return (
       <Router>
          <div>
            <nav>
              <ul>
               <li>
                 <Link to='/profile'>Profile</Link>
               </li>
                <li className='right-edge-pusher'>
                  <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                    <Link to='/search'>Search</Link>
                 </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/profile' element={<ProfilePage/>}/>
              <Route path='/' element={<HomePage/>}/>
              <Route path='/search' element={<SearchPage/>}/>
            </Routes>
          </div>
      </Router>
     );
}

export default App;
```

I tried to install every potential required dependency I saw online as well as breaking down the code into different parts like other tutorials I found did. I continually receive the exact same errors.

Comment: That error about `useRef` and the `BrowserRouter` is caused by `React` being undefined for some reason. See the [source code](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L301). Have you made sure that ***all*** of your project dependencies are actually installed, correctly?

Comment: I'm still new so how could I check? I was pretty sure they were as I used `npm i` to install everything I found online that could help.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you can check what react version is installed by running `npm list react` in the terminal in the project's root directory.

Comment: No worries, thank you! Here is the response: `@testing-library/react@13.4.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
└── react@18.2.0`

Comment: I doubt it'll reproduce, but think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that hopefully reproduces the issue that we can inspect live?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :) I don't know how to use codesandbox but I have also decided to put this project on hold and work on building a better understanding of react-router and typescript separately first and then come back to the issue.